# How would one calculate the time it takes for an object immersed in liquid nitrogen to reach a specific temperature?

Tags: thermodynamics, heat-conduction

I have an aluminium object which will be immersed in liquid nitrogen for a specified amount of time. I would like to know, if the object is initially at room temperature, how long it would take for it to reach -80 °C after immersion.

My understanding that I could use Newton's law of cooling in the form:

$$T=T_∞+(T_0−T_∞)e^{-at}$$

where:
$T_0$ is the initial temperature of Al object (20 °C);
$T_∞$ is the temperature of the liquid nitrogen (-196 °C);
$T$ is the desired final temperature (-80 °C);
and $a = \frac{hA}{mc_p}$, where $h$ is the heat transfer coeff, $m$ the mass, $A$ the surface area, and $c_p$ the specific heat capacity of Al.

I can obtain values for all of those variables, excluding the heat transfer coefficient. How can the heat transfer coeff be calculated and perhaps more importantly, is this approach even correct?

Comment: At the initial stage, evaporation of nitrogen will occur with the formation of a gas cavity. Then the cavity will pop up. Then, perhaps, there will be a cooling according to Newton. To determine the parameters of heat transfer, you need to know what form an object has, what is its mass, how deeply this object is immersed in nitrogen.

Comment: @AlexTrounev I am aware of the object's mass, its form (if by that you means its surface area or volume), and I know how deeply immersed the object is in the liquid nitrogen. With that in mind, how would I go about calculating the time taken to cool?

Comment: Do you want an answer in general?I have no such answer . I can answer only for particular values of parameters using a numerical model.

Comment: You need to solve the transient heat conduction equation within the object, or find a literature solution to the transient heat conduction equation for an object of that approximate shape, with the asymptotic (internal) Nussult number (dimensionless heat transfer coefficient) presented as part of the results.  This will enable you to determine an upper bound to the amount of time required.